# Neural net: undefined columns selected

Tags: r, neural-network

I'm trying to create a neural network for my training data using neuralnet. I understand that I cannot do Cluster ~. and hence I have pasted the column names in ' f '. The first 2 codes run fine.

```
colnames = colnames(train.set[,1:44])
f = as.formula(paste("Cluster ~", paste(colnames, collapse = " + ")))
nn = neuralnet(f,
               data = train.set,
               hidden = 3,
               act.fct = "logistic",
               linear.output = FALSE,
               lifesign = "minimal")
```

However, when I run the nn code to train my model, it shows this error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , model.list$variables) : undefined columns selected
```

I'm saw that someone suggested that train.set was a matrix and not a data frame but I'm sure that train.set is already a dataframe. How do I correct this error?

Comment: its difficult to help without any data. Could you show us your data? One thing to try is to reduce the number of columns in train.set, so that you are sure that the, say, 3 variable-columns are certainly present. column Cluster should not be part of the 44 training-columns, of course. does the command > train.set[,colnames] work or does it give an error? good luck :)

Comment: thank you for replying! My dataset has 45 columns, the last column is Cluster (which is what I am trying to learn and predict). When I do str(train.set), it gives me tibble [42,034 × 45] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame).  the command > train.set[,colnames] works as well.

Comment: try converting your data from a tbl_df/tbl/data.frame to a classic dataframe, using as.data.frame(train.set) ? there are some subsetting differences between tibbles and data.frames, which sometimes causes problems